# reading from registry fails in vista enterprise

Tags: mfc, registry

I try to read registry key from registry . I start with Admin privilage .Read fails only in vista enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the registry key?

What's the specific error?

Have you verified that the key actually exists?

Have you verified that Admins have permission to read the key? It would be unusual, but this situation is not impossible.

When I'm unable to effectively debug an issue like this, I find ProcMon (from the [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)) to be an invaluable tool.